# Lifetime requirements for storage of std::exception_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

Given the example about `std::exception_ptr` from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_exception), would it be legal to shorten the code in the following way?
If all the handling is done inside the catch-block, there should be no need to store the `std::exception_ptr` at an outer or even at global scope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
 
void handle_eptr(std::exception_ptr eptr) // passing by value is ok
{
    try {
        if (eptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception \"" << e.what() << "\"\n";
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    try {
        std::string().at(1); // this generates an std::out_of_range
    } catch(...) {
        handle_eptr(std::current_exception()); // CHANGE: HANDLING THE std::exception_ptr AS R-VALUE INSIDE THE CATCH BLOCK
    }
} // destructor for std::out_of_range called here, when the eptr is destructed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, the program is valid.

from cppreference:

> The exception object referenced by an std::exception_ptr remains valid
>   as long as there remains at least one std::exception_ptr that is
>   referencing it: std::exception_ptr is a shared-ownership smart pointer

in this case `eptr` will make sure that the value returned from `std::current_exception` will not get out of scope. when in doubt, think that the lifetime of `std::exception_ptr` follows the same scoping rules of `std::shared_ptr`, since they both "shared-ownership smart pointer"

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but the point of the cppreference code is that the exception pointer allows you to persist the lifetime of the exception outside of the catch block, and without rethrowing.

So your code looks legal, but it would not fullfill the purpose thst the cppreference code does.

Comment: Maybe my purpose is slightly different. I'm already happy being able to outsource (less code duplication) a full-fledged exception handler handling various exceptions including logging facilities. Therefore I don't need lifetime extension.